# Android Adding Views or changing Visibility of Views as Game progresses

Tags: android-widget

I am trying to write a simple game where progress through the levels gives the user more functions, i.e. another View appears which adds to the things the user can do in the game.  In particular I want to add ZoomControls at the moment if that matters.
As far as I know or can figure out you must add Views in OnCreate.  Therefore I have tried setting the View to invisible in OnCreate, with the intention of changing it to visible later during the game.  But the game is executed in a separate Custom View class so also can't see a way to change the visibility of the View which is back in the Main Activity.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Worked it out, used a custom interface.  Then had to use UI thread to make changes to View objects.  No answer received yet but bonus number of spam mails since signing up!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, used a custom interface to send data back. Then had to use main UI thread to make changes to View objects.

Also, if you are new here like me, tip, if you get no replies your reputation quickly goes downhill without you realising it.  Answer your own questions if you can.